# SuperSet Hive Query issue - expected data in columnar format

Tags: python, hive, pyhive, apache-superset

I'm having a weird issue w/ running following Hive query via SuperSet (apache incubator):

```
SELECT 
   date,
   sum(1) visits,
   sum(price) revenue
FROM
   visits 
WHERE
   date BETWEEN '2017-07-21' AND '2017-07-25'
   AND country = 'US'
GROUP BY
   date,
   browser
```

Error I'm getting can be caught in the terminal from which I ran the superset (VM virtual box virtual machine running ubuntu):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userxx/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/sql_lab.py", line 182, in execute_sql
    db_engine_spec.handle_cursor(cursor, query, session)
  File "/home/userxx/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/db_engine_specs.py", line 726, in handle_cursor
    resp = cursor.fetch_logs()
  File "/home/userxx/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/db_engines/hive.py", line 34, in fetch_logs
    response.results.rows, 'expected data in columnar format'
AssertionError
```

The fun part is that it's working OK when date period is 7/21 - 7/24. I figured it has to do w/ memory, but adding browsers into the story (as a group by option) didn't change the behavior (my logic was that adding it would break the query even for period 7/21 - 7/24 due to increased number of rows).

Needless to say, the query runs perfectly when started from e.g. *SQL Developer Tool*.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version was 0.18.x and the issue disappeared in 0.19